# Selenium Python get_attribute("src") returns None, eventhough there is a "src" attribute

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, getattribute

Selenium Python get_attribute("src") returns None, eventhough there is a "src" attribute

Code Trials:

```
link = f"https://duckduckgo.com/?q={searchtext}&iax=images&ia=images"
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(link)
time.sleep(2)
tabbutton = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.tile:nth-child(3)")
webdriver.ActionChains(driver).click(tabbutton).perform()
imagelink = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.detail__pane:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > a:nth-child(1) > img:nth-child(3)")
src = imagelink.get_attribute("src")
print(src)
```

It always prints "None" and every other attribute is working.
The html is:

```
<img style="width: 218.333px; height: 262px; display: block;" alt="Flower Blume Pflanze Lila Gelb - ZoPix.NET" class="detail__media__img-highres  js-detail-img  js-detail-img-high" src="//external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=http%3A%2F%2Fen.zopix.net%2Fimage_upload%2F138342-flower-blume-pflanze-lila.JPG&amp;f=1&amp;nofb=1">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To print the value of the *src* attribute you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the [*visibility_of_element_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50468629/python-selenium-wait-until-element-is-fully-loaded/50474905#50474905) and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "img.detail__media__img-highres[alt^='Flower Blume Pflanze Lila Gelb - ZoPix']"))).get_attribute("src"))
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//img[@class='detail__media__img-highres  js-detail-img  js-detail-img-high' and @alt='Flower Blume Pflanze Lila Gelb - ZoPix.NET']"))).get_attribute("src"))
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```